# Bootstrap Nav bar expanding gets cut off (with video)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am making a react app and have installed the latest bootstrap via

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and

```
npm install bootstrap jquery
```

and

```
npm install jquery popper.js
```

My Navbar works fine when the window is wide, but when you decrease the width and the Navbar becomes a dropdown navbar, it does not work properly.  As you click to expand, it starts to expand, but then gets cut off, making it seem like it stops or goes off the page.  I can only see the last item.

In my src/index.js I have
and

```
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

My Navbar code is simple stuff

```
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <Links />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

I have tried removing  and removing different classes, it seems to be the button toggle action that is where the trouble is rooted.

UPDATE: Link to video to visualize the issue: [videoLink](https://streamable.com/ojpk1a)

UPDATE:  Here is the full code:

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <title>test Site</title>
<style>
#body_id {
    background-image: url(../../assets/myImg/baking_background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="body_id">
  <div id="root">
</body>
</html>
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'

import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

app/index.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Navbar</a>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  )
}

export default App
```

I also tried putting the bootstrap in the index.html like this:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <title>test Site</title>
</head>
<body id="body_id">
  <div id="root">
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'

//import 'jquery';
//import 'popper.js';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with these updates:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body_id">
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

app/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
function App() {
  return (
            <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="navbar-header">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
                        <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                  <ul className="nav navbar-nav">     
                <li>Create</li>
                <li> Login</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
         </nav>
)
}
export default App
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back sooner, but I would probably have reworked it.  Excellent reworking on your part  For anyone else who views this there are some templates and examples at https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I honestly did not identify what the original issue was, maybe the bootstrap I was including in index.html I also noticed the class names for navbar are slightly different in the new and old bootstrap navbar (toggle vs toggler) either way, thanks for your help along the way!

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably a missing **jquery** dependency.

First, install jquery and popper.js via npm:

npm install jquery popper.js

Import jquery and popper.js in your src/index.js file before Bootstrap's
JavaScript:

javascript

import 'jquery';

import 'popper.js';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';

```
Your Navbar component code appears to be OK.
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately it is still cutting short

Comment: I added a video as well

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this formatted in the comment, so unfortunately I've had to put it as another answer.  I hope no one minds.

Make sure the container holding Navbar has enough width. If it’s too narrow, it can cause elements to get cut off when the Navbar collapses.

Try

Jsx

```
  <div className="container-fluid"> {/* Check the container width */}


  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg">


{/* ... */}


  </nav>


</div>
```

The "fas fa-bars" class seems OK. but, you might want to make sure that the icon isn’t too large.  It could push other Navbar items out of view.

Try:

Jsx

```
<i className="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i> {/* Adjust icon size with "fa-lg" */}
```

Things you’ve probably checked, but just in case, and it could be helpful to others less experienced:

Check there are no elements within the Navbar that are too wide, causing overflow. E.g text, icons, or other elements.

Do you have any CSS applied to your Navbar or surrounding elements? check if it is affecting the layout. Custom styles, sometimes, conflict with Bootstrap's default styles.

Very obvious, sorry, but again, just in case:  Check you’re using a compatible version of Bootstrap with the installed packages. Bootstrap's JavaScript components are sometimes sensitive to the version of jQuery and Popper.js.

Check for JavaScript errors These can sometimes give clues about what's going wrong.

If you have custom JavaScript code related to the Navbar or button toggle, try disabling temporarily.

Comment: I tested it out without using the icons, just text with same problem.  I tried adding fa-lg.  I did those npm installs this week, is there a different way I need to install them to make sure they are up to date? Not sure what you mean about making sure the container holding the navbar has enough room.  the nav is the top element. Inspect element window shows no errors. I will keep trying